# Eclipse plugin not getting loaded

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am working on Eclipse 4.2.1 and writing a Java project. I need to use a plugin developed by a third party. Other developers in my team are able to use the plugin by putting it in the plugins folder and the plugin takes effect. However, for me the plugin does not take effect and I am not able to see the plugin in the InstallationDetails -Plugin menu. I have tried to debug the issue by running the following:

```
eclipse.exe -clean -debug -consoleLog
```

However, I dont see any errors in the logs that might give a hint as to why the plugin is not launched. Any clues would be highly appreciated. Below is the output --

```
  Start VM: -Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equi
nox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4
.2.1.v201209141800\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equ
inox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launc
her_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-clean
-clean
-console
-consoleLog
-debug
-vm C:\ToolChain\win64\jdk-1.6.0_35\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equi
nox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
Install location:
    file:/c:/softwaredownloads/eclipse/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/c:/softwaredownloads/eclipse/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/c:/softwaredownloads/eclipse/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/c:/softwaredownloads/eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v2
0120830-144521.jar
Framework classpath:
    file:/c:/softwaredownloads/eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v2
0120830-144521.jar
Splash location:
    C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v20
1209141800\splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/C:/softwaredownloads/eclipse/eclipse/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 37
Starting application: 6273
osgi> Application Started: 18986
```

Comment: For reference I am writng the logs -

Comment: Start VM: -Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equi
nox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4
.2.1.v201209141800\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equ
inox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813\eclipse_1503.dll

Comment: -startup C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launc
her_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-clean
-clean
-console
-consoleLog
-debug
-vm C:\ToolChain\win64\jdk-1.6.0_35\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equi
nox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
Install location:
    file:/c:/softwaredownloads/eclipse/eclipse/

Comment: Configuration file:
    file:/c:/softwaredownloads/eclipse/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/c:/softwaredownloads/eclipse/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/c:/softwaredownloads/eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v2
0120830-144521.jar
Framework classpath:
    file:/c:/softwaredownloads/eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v2
0120830-144521.jar
Splash location:
    C:\softwaredownloads\eclipse\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v20

Comment: Put all this information in the question, not in comments

Comment: Try to start from the command line as eclipse -clean

Comment: As I already tried that. Didnt work. Also the logs dont indicate any error as to why loading of the plugin has failed. Is it that the plugin was not just picked up ?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are the other developers on your team using?

Answer (score 3):

p2 is now the only mechanism to install Eclipse extensions. There are various ways to invoke it. The one similar to the old mechanism of dropping plugins into the plugins folder is dropping extensions into the [dropins](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/p2_dropins_format.html) folder.

If the plugin is just a jar file, just drop it into `dropins`. Otherwise create a subdirectory for it and put all the files in there.

Then, run `eclipsec -initialize`. When that finishes, start Eclipse as you usually would.

Comment: Hello..thanks for your comments. Unfortunately they don't have a p2 update site. The plugin comes as a folder which has several files inside like plugin.xml, plugin.properties and other jar files. I created a subfolder under dropins and placed by plugin there and ran initialize and started eclipse. Still didnt work. Any more ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: dropins is the way to do it, as per http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Dropins Perhaps add them to dropins and then launch again with -clean

Answer (score 0):

If your custom plug-in is provided by a third party, do they have an p2 update site ?

The preferred way to install new plug-ins is now via p2, if your third party does provide the plug-in via an update site, just go to Help -> Install New Software.

Comment: Hello..thanks for your comments. Unfortunately they don't have a p2 update site. The plugin comes as a folder which has several files inside like plugin.xml, plugin.properties and other jar files. I created a subfolder under dropins and placed by plugin there and ran initialize and started eclipse. Still didnt work. Any more ideas would be highly appreciated.